# How can I add a line on my XML figure?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Hello I have this triangle that I created in XML but I want to add a line on my triangle. How can I do this ?

Here is my XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="135"
            android:pivotX="7%"
            android:pivotY="65%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >

                              <solid
                    android:color="@color/green" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>




    </item>

</selector>
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Use a LayerList

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you want to create line in the same file which is posted above by you.

If you want to draw line in your activity.xml file then you can do that by using `ImageView` widget. You need to have line color(which ever you want) defined in colors.xml file or you can directly hard code the RBG color in `ImageView` widget like this.

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/line" 
android:gravity="center"  //you can give gravity to line as you want
android:width="match_parent"  // you can give width as much u want
android:height="2dp"  //here its 2dp which gives thickness to the line
android:src="#000000"/>  //line will be black color change color of your choice
```

These will create the line for you in activity.xml file so below this you can draw your triangle. Hope this will help you.